# javascript - onclick() requires two clicks to trigger event

Tags: events, onclick

My problem is that when `onclick()` is triggered the first time, nothing happens, but when it is clicked a second time, the code is executed.

The `onclick()` should turn the `<div>` into a png image file and save it to the computer.

HTML (the TableDay function refers to a function I wrote which basically makes it easier to create the table):

```
<div id="TableDiv">
<table id="Table">
<tr>
<th>Dag\Uur</th><th>1</th><th>2</th><th>3</th><th>4</th><th>5</th><th>6</th><th>7</th><th>8</th><th>9</th>
</tr>
<?php
TableDay("Maandag",1);
TableDay("Dinsdag",10);
TableDay("Woensdag",19);
TableDay("Donderdag",28);
TableDay("Vrijdag",37);
?>
</table>
</div>
<a id="Image" href="##" onclick="printTable()">Download</a>
```

(Text is Dutch)

The `onclick="printTable()"` refers to the following Javascript code:

```
<script>
var element = $("#TableDiv"); // global variable
var getCanvas; // global variable

function printTable() {
    html2canvas(element, {
    onrendered: function (canvas) {
        getCanvas = canvas;
    }});

    var imgageData = getCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    // Now browser starts downloading it instead of just showing it
    var newData = imgageData.replace(/^data:image\/png/, "data:application/octet-stream");
    $("#Image").attr("download", "Rooster.png").attr("href", newData);
}
</script>
```

What is happening exactly and how can I make it so that the `<a>` reference in the html code only needs to be clicked once?